# Getting string serves reply ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i got from my customer string that I need to get to the server and get an answer.

this is the string:

```
http://XXX.YYY.DDD.WWW:8082/My_ws?Myapp=Myprice&Mydip=123&itemno=123456
```

and i get any string as Result.

i try this in ajax and jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
       ServiceCallID: 1,
       url: MyString,
       type: 'POST',
       data: '{"itemno": "' + itemno+ '"}',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       success:
       function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
          ALL = (data.d).toString();
       }
       },
       error:
       function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus);
       }
                });
```

how to "talk" with the server and get the Result from my string ?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting success or error? And what `console.log(data)` shows in case of success ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem. But usually in ajax you pass a dictionary instance to data and not a string. Like:

`data: { "itemno": itemno}`

Instead of:

`data: '{"itemno": "' + itemno+ '"}'`

Comment: @t.pimentel jQuery's `$.ajax()` function takes either plain objects (which it will serialize to a string), arrays or strings. Also, in JavaScript, "dictionaries" are commonly referred to as "objects", or less frequently, "hashes". Now if your question was more directed to "what the heck kind of funky syntax is that `data` construction?" then I'm in wholehearted agreement. :)

Comment: As @t.pimentel alluded to, your `data` value is weird. It's perfectly acceptable to pass either a string or an object, but what you're passing is going to be the literal string: `{"itemno": "' + itemno+ '"}`, not a string that includes the value of the variable `itemno`. If you're still having problems after correcting that error, post additional details, like the error you're getting and relevant console logs.